# Custom domain under SSL with Google Sites?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-classic-sites, g-suite-administrator

Is there a way to have a Google Sites hosted as say, `sites.example.com/foo` rather than `sites.google.com/a/example.com/foo` while supporting HTTPS? It seems to me that only HTTP redirect and no SSL support is available.

Anybody to confirm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can now publish your Google Site at a custom URL, *with* SSL, and it even works without a redirect.

1. Publish your Google Site and make it visible to the public (under Share options, set it to *'Anyone can find and view'*). As long as the Google Site is not public, it will still redirect to a `sites.google.com/*` address.
2. Create a CNAME DNS record for your (sub)domain, pointing to `ghs.googlehosted.com`
3. Add a *'Web Mapping'* according to Google's guide: https://support.google.com/a/answer/7392423?hl=en
4. Once your DNS record and the web mapping are active (might take a bit), your custom domain actually redirects from http to https automatically; Google generated a LetsEncrypt certificate for you in the background.

Comment: Google Site cannot work on custom domain if it's not public to everyone. It will always redirect. It's not obvious, couldn't find this in Google Help so let Google bot index this comment to help others!

Answer (score 1):

In your Admin Console, under Company Profile, Select "Custom URL's"

Make changes as you see fit.

Yes, it will say http://sites.example.com (or whatever you decide)

If you also have "Enable SSL" set in Security | Basic Settings, then users will be taken to the HTTPS: site pages (others too). 
Yes, this is a redirect, but you still tell others, and create links to, sites.example.com/foo and it IS HTTPS:

Let us know.

Enable SSL "Automatically enforce Secure Socket Layer (SSL) connections when your users access Gmail, Calendar, Docs, and Sites."

Comment: Thanks for your follow-up. I guess I am stuck then. The redirect defeats the whole point of having the DNS alias. I guess I will have to wait until Google let us upload an SSL cert for Google Sites.

Comment: The Google "sites" (mail, calendar, sites, etc.) all run SSL off of Google servers, not yours. Besides, Redirection is the only way Google Apps work (with or without SSL).  If you enable SSL, you ARE getting SSL connections.  The purpose of the URL settings is so people and crawlers see the links as pages.yourdomain.com. (instead of Google)

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be possible to redirect https by Google Domains:

https://support.google.com/domains/answer/4522141?hl=en#zippy=%2Cforwarding-over-ssl

https://www.steegle.com/google-sites/how-to/assign-custom-url-domain-personal